# Copying formula to inserted columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, insert

I created a workbook that inserts columns based on a value on the main sheet.  The issue I'm having is that the new columns need to copy the formulas located in the main column, but apply to that new column.

I was able to use the OFFSET function to accomplish this task in rows that are pulling data from a different sheet.  The formula used was:

```
=OFFSET(DATA!$C$2,COLUMN()-2,0)
```

Each new column pulls the correct data from the correct sheet.

The problem with the other formulas is that they pertain to that sheet and aren't simply pulling data from a different sheet.

For example, I have SUM functions and PRODUCT functions to name a few on this particular sheet.

Is there a formula or VBA code that can be used to automatically SUM the right cells when a new column is inserted?  A couple of the formulas that I have are:

```
 =SUM(E8:(OFFSET(E11,0,0)))
```

```
=PRODUCT(OFFSET(F13,0,0),$C$12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with VBA.  I am curious how you are creating the columns in the new sheets to begin with if not with VBA.

If I were doing this in VBA, I would do something like the following:

```
Cells(row, column).Value = "=SUM(" & cellReference & ":" & cellReference & ")"
```

`cellReference` above refers to a calculated cell reference based on the target.  I would need more information in order to be more specific with my answer, e.g. screenshots, code snippets, etc.

If you were not using VBA, then I you could try using the `ADDRESS` function, which allows you to specify the sheet name.

P.S. I would have left a comment to get clarification, but I am still trying to build up my stack cred.  ;)